# What is Layout Effect in React Profiler

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-devtools

I am currently trying to improve my React App performance and I noticed in the Profiler that the bottleneck is in the Layout effects. Any idea what this Layout effect means?
I am using Material Table and Material UI, which rerenders when a checkbox is clicked.
Thank you!

[image: React Profiler Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

I assume this has to do with the [useLayout hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#uselayouteffect) from React. You can also find more information about the profiler in this [Github thread](https://github.com/reactwg/react-18/discussions/76).